# Rails Engine with RSpec and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rails-engines

I followed a few tutorials and docs of FactoryGirl to use with RSpec. Currently I get one error when trying to use FactoryGirl.create:

```
describe "GenericRecipesController" do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "displays list of generic recipes" do
        generic_recipe = FactoryGirl.create(:generic_recipe)
        visit '/recipe'
        response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

And the error:

```
 GenericRecipesController GET 'index' displays list of generic recipes
 Failure/Error: generic_recipe = FactoryGirl.create(:generic_recipe)
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant GenericRecipe
 # ./spec/integration/generic_recipes_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The rest of [code is there](https://github.com/valk/edible-recipe/tree/master/spec).

Comment: Here's an upvote for having your full source code available before asking a question.

Comment: Also, can you show us the code for your factory?

Comment: Thanks, the factory is here: https://github.com/valk/edible-recipe/blob/master/spec/factories.rb

Comment: Amazing how I'm so used to ask for further pieces of code that I didn't think of looking at your repo...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
factory :generic_recipe, class: EdibleRecipe::GenericRecipe do
    # ...
end
```

I think problem in a nesting model in module

**Upd**: delete file /spec/factories.rb, in file /spec/support/factories.rb make

```
factory :generic_recipe, class: EdibleRecipe::GenericRecipe do
```

When you will run tests, probably will see 'can not load table'. Make

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

and try again.

Comment: I was going to post the exact same answer. Now I'm puzzled.

Comment: I'm puzzled too. Valk, can you commit tests too? In repo i didn't see them

Comment: @hellaxe Sorry, just saw your question. I added the test, there's only one though here https://github.com/valk/edible-recipe/blob/master/spec/integration/generic_recipes_spec.rb.

Comment: Valk, i've seen the test and got to you solution. At least i tried on local copy of your repo and this works

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a GenericRecipe model in your app.  Factory Girl is looking for a Model called GenericReciper and can't find it.

Comment: I do have it here https://github.com/valk/edible-recipe/blob/master/app/models/edible_recipe/generic_recipe.rb